# Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. QLA2300

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, scsi, hostadapter

My system is an Altix3000 running: `(Linux sgialtix 2.4.21-sgi304r1 #1 SMP Sat Jan 29 22:43:29 PST 2005 ia64 ia64 ia64 GNU/Linux) (redhat-release=redhat-release-3AS-8.3)`.
Which command do I use to list World Wide Name information of the QLA2300 HBA? I tried `/proc/scsi` and `/proc/xscsi` but I found nothing there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: I have connected the SGI Altix3000 to an SGI Storage Box, to map LUN to the SGI server i need to have the WWN that's why im looking for the command to get the FC card info.

Answer (score 2):

I use QLogic cards in Linux. For this I use:

```
cat /sys/class/fc_host/<host3>/port_name
```

The `<host>` entry is different for each FC processor and host.

Your FC switch will also show this value when you connect the ports.

Comment: I don't see /sys/class/fc_host what i see is scsi_host

Comment: @AlBouazizi, I was searching around... check the output of "/var/cluster/cxfs_client-scripts/cxfs-enumerate-wwns".  Sorry I don't know Altix all that well...

Comment: /var/cluster/: No such file or directory  Thankk you for effort

Answer (score 0):

now, it seems to be a fairly complex process. According to [this](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-easily-find-wwns-of-qlogic-hba.html) its supposed to be in /proc/scsi, and you can pull out the port numbers with egrep.

Comment: What i was asking: i need to have the WWN of the Fibre Channel: QLogic Corp. QLA2300 64-bit FC-AL Adapter (rev 01).

Comment: Journeyman Geek, in /proc/ no scsi dir found- in /proc/xscsi found 2 files(dksc,scsi) and one dir ctrl with nothing is there.